# Performance impact of using PostgreSQL "IF NOT EXISTS" and similar for migrations

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-migration

PostgreSQL has the ability to do idempotent operations for most migration type queries. For instance, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo"` or `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "bar"()` etc. What would be the performance impact of using these types of queries instead of the more traditional migration table that checks if each incremental migration file has been run?

Comment: Can you describe the second approach in detail?

Comment: @David did my answer help in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The migration tools like `liquidate`, `flyweight` have the capability to check existence of an object and when not found then create that object. The migration script should be written in that manner for performance reason. Once can make the migration tool call an idempotent object creation script which uses syntax like '`REATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foo"` as you described. So from performance point of view this must be done one way or another.

The migration tools provides some additional benefits like - you can virtually add any precondition before running a script. That precondition can be as wide as what SQL offers on all the objects you have. 
It provides version control mechanism, as scripts are run release over release, those scripts can be accumulated and run in order to recreate the database. When these scripts are written using solid preconditions and idempotent scripts as you mentioned, they wouldn't be slow.

In conclusion I would use both - migration script with pre-condition plus the idempotent syntax.